# Get result from query as custom List of Objects

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement SQL query for Bar chart which shows volumes per day for last 10 days. For example I have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `payment_transactions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
);
```

I get this example result (grouped per day):

```
Date       | Amount| Number of transactions per day |
11-11-2018 | 30    | 3                              |
11-12-2018 | 230   | 13                             |
```

JPA query:

```
public List<DashboardDTO> findAll() {

        String hql = "SELECT date(created_at) AS cdate, sum(amount) AS amount, count(id) AS nooftransaction "
                + "FROM payment_transactions WHERE date(created_at)>=date(now()- interval 10 DAY) "
                + "AND date(created_at)<date(now()) GROUP BY date(created_at)";

        TypedQuery<DashboardDTO> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Merchants.class);
        List<DashboardDTO> data = query.getResultList();

        return data;
    }
```

Java Object:

```
public class DashboardDTO {

    private Date date;
    private int amount;
    private int number_of_transactions;

    public DashboardDTO(Date date, int amount, int number_of_transactions) {
        this.date = date;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.number_of_transactions = number_of_transactions;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getNumber_of_transactions() {
        return number_of_transactions;
    }

    public void setNumber_of_transactions(int number_of_transactions) {
        this.number_of_transactions = number_of_transactions;
    }
}
```

How I can implement the query properly? I would like to get the result as `List<DashboardDTO>` without using Entity?

Comment: You want to execute native query and map the result to java object?

Comment: Yes - that is the result the tI would like to get.

Comment: Please check out [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) article. In particular `DTO projections using a ConstructorResult` section

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is add `@Entity`, `@Id` to your `DashboardDTO` and make your native sql alias name match the DTO's property name.

```
@Entity
public class DashboardDTO {
  @Id
  private Date cdate;
  private int amount;
  private int numberOfTransactions;
  ...
}

public List<DashboardDTO> findAll() {
  String hql = "SELECT ... AS cdate, ... AS amount, ... AS number_of_transactions FROM ...";
  return entityManager.createNativeQuery(hql, DashboardDTO.class).getResultList();
}
```